# Where should I place functionality to convert between types?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, c#-4.0

I have two instances in an application where I need to implement functionality to convert an object from one type to another. One to go from a domain object to another domain object, another to go from a domain object an XmlDocument.

The way I have initially set it up is to include a `ToXml()` and `ToMyOtherDO()` within `DomainObject1` and `DomainObject2` respectively.

The functionality in `ToXml` isn't really specific to the implementation of `DomainObject1` and could probably live anywhere. `ToMyOtherDO()` has functionality very specific to the type it lives in. Both perform type conversions but are quite different.

My question is, have I placed this functionality in the correct place? Would this functionality be better placed in a helper class? Or some place else - perhaps overriding the explicit casting operator?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with `ToXml()` and `ToMyOtherDO()`  and would do it the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually like to put this kind of functionality in [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

**EDIT**: *Explanation*
I generally prefer to put this kind of functionality in extension methods because I don't feel that the class that needs to be "converted" really needs to know how to do the conversion. This provides some decoupling. You can easily change the format of your XML without changing the object that you are converting to XML (especially useful when the object to be converted is in a seperate assembly).

You will eventually run into a situation where you want to convert your domain object to something that it does not really need to know about. For example, maybe you want to convert your domain object to a [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) `JObject`. The assembly containing your domain object wouldn't need a reference to the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) library if you used extension methods to handle the conversion in a separate assembly.

The extension methods are great especially when dealing with the Entity Framework. The code for the entity classes are auto-generated, so you can't just add a `ToXML()` or `ToJObject()` to the class.

These are just my preferences, and I don't *always* use extension methods to handle this kind of functionality. It's just another great tool to have in your arsenal, for solving these kinds of problems.

Comment: Could you explain *why* you prefer to put it in an extension method instead of in the DO directly? What would the advantages be? And would the class containing the EM be specific to this DO or could it contain any arbitrary EMs for other classes as well? I'd really be interested to hear your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

I would place it in a static class as extension methods. This way you can call it like an instance method but it doesn't clutter your domain object's code.

Answer (score 0):

The `ToXml()` function should be placed in a helper class, if it's not specific to the object.

I would suggest implementing ToMyOtherDO() as an extension method of your class, since it is specific to it.

```
public void ToMyOtherDo(this MyClass object1)
{
    //Do stuff to object1
}
```

You will then be able to call `myobject.ToMyOtherDo()` (considering myobject as a MyClass object)

Comment: The return type of this method is void.  There is no way to get the converted object.  This should probably return `DomainObject2`

Comment: This is just an example, Sio can adjust the function to his liking.

Answer (score 0):

If `ToXml` is not type type specific, I would do as blachniet and others suggested, and put it in an extension method.

If `ToMyOtherDO` only uses public members, then an extension method is a good place for it.  However, if `ToMyOtherDO` requires private member, then it must be the type it is converting from.